# Could someone tell me if im right about what these parts of the code do

Tags: flutter, dart

Could someone tell me if im right about what these parts of the code do:

This is JSON to string conversion?

```
factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
    userId: json["userId"],
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    body: json["body"],
  );
```

And this would be string to JSON conversion?

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "userId": userId,
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "body": body,
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, `Json` equivalent type is `Map`. The first `fromJson()` method is converting `Map` to a `Post model class` which is custom defined.

Your Post model class will look like this.

```
Post{
final int userId;
final int id;
final String title;
final String body;

Post({required this.userId,required this.id,required this.title,required this.body});
}
```

Using raw `Map` data type is handy and dangerous. You have to memorize all key names. So, you first convert `json response` to `Map` and then `Map` to `Post model class`. That's what `fromJson` does. The process is as follows.

```
///Converts Json to Map
Map<String,dynamic> mapData = jsonDecode(json);

///Converts Map to Post class
Post post = Post.fromJson(mapData);
```

`toJson()` method is reverse of `fromJson()`. It converts `Post class` to `Map` data type. And then you convert it to `Json` for api requests. The process is like this.

```
/// Conoverts Post class to Map
Map<String,dynamic> mapData = post.toJson();

///Converts Map to Json
String json = jsonEncode(mapData);
```

**Have fun :)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and for the effort put in the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's totally true, the `fromJson` factory will create the Post class instance from a JSON `Map`.
and the to `toJson` will return a JSON Map to use it.

it's totally right